# How to use function decorators to check type of function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

How would I use a function decorator to check the argument of another function? I'm trying to wrap my head around function decorators but it's super confusing.

Ideally I would like it work like this, you pass in an int and a function below and the function works else you get a type error.

```
@check(int)
def printer(arg):
    print(arg)
```

```
>>> printer(5)
5
```

This is what I tried but it doesn't work.

```
def check(typ):

    def validate(args):
        if type(args) == typ:
           return validate(args)
        else:
           raise TypeError

    return validate
```

Any advice or guidance would be appreciated, been really trying to wrap my head around decorators.

Comment: It's not a specific error, the code is incorrect because I don't understand how to structure it because I am having trouble understanding how to pass in arguments from the decorator and compare it to the functions arguments.

Comment: your main topic is to get function type and in code you were checking the arguments type. please ask clearly what you want to know. and in answer i have written about decorator in laymans language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`check(int)` still has to return a function.

```
def check(typ):
    def checker(f):
        def checked_func(arg):
            if isinstance(arg, typ):
                return f(arg)
            else:
                raise TypeError
        return checked_func
    return checker
```

Now, `_` is the actual decorator returned by `check`, and `_` takes the original function and wraps it in *another* function which checks the type of the argument, and either returns the result of the original function applied to the argument, or raises a TypeError.

It might be easier to follow if we break it into more pieces.

```
int_checker = check(int)

@int_checker
def printer(arg):
    print(arg)
```

Comment: Thank you! It was where you called f(arg) I couldn't conceptualize but seeing it written out makes so much sense. I was having trouble in the order these were being wrapped. How come return checker does not take in any arguments?

Comment: It helps me to build decorators up from the bottom. Start by defining the function you want `printer` to be replaced by, then wrap that with a function that takes `printer` as an argument and uses that in the replacement. Then wrap *that* in a function that abstracts away the type you are checking.

Comment: Also keep in mind that decoration is just syntactic sugar for a combination of function application and variable assignment: `@func(x) def foo():...` is the same as `def foo():...; foo = func(foo)`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

In python everything is a object, even the functions too.
let me write the function in a different way just to express

```
def fun(arg):
```

can be expressed as

```
fun(a variable) = function(arg) # just like we write in JS
```

so as we can also assign different value to a variable. same we can assign a different function to a given function name.

in short meaning of a decorator is to assign a different function to the function name over which it is written

```
@deco
def func(arg):
```

is same as

```
 func = deco(func)
```

and to do that the return type of a decorator should be pointer to another function.

So decorator syntax is like  -

```
def deco_func(func): # the parameter is a function
    def wrap_func(args):  #the args are the argument of original function
        #what ever you want to do
        return func(args) #call for original function
retunr wrap_func   # returning of the pointer of the wrap function.
```